# Get back branches that were deleted locally

Tags: git

A bunch of SO questions/answers on pruning the local repo from origin, but I couldn't find an answer for this:

I have a repo `test` with branches `master`, `branch1`, `branch2`. I ran `git branch -d branch1 branch2`, and now they no longer show. Let's say I want to get these back in my local repo. How do I do this? (Note: This is for learning, so I don't want to use `reflog` to restore; I'm trying to understand why I can't get the branches back using the commands I've learned to pull from the server.)

I tried doing `git fetch --all`, as well as `reset --hard origin/master`, and a couple other things, but while git shows the branches existing on remote (`git branch --all` returns `/remote/origin/test1` as well as for `/origin/test2`), I can't get them back on my local copy.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By fetching you are updating the remote branches (references) on your local. You could create local branches from them:

```
git branch branch1 origin/branch1
```

And in case you really lost them locally and have no remote references, you can always check the reflog to get the IDs and create branches from them

```
git branch branch1 some-old-revision-id
```

Comment: Ok, so `fetch` is basically saying to sync my local git's record to match what exists/doesn't exist on the server. (I've read the documentation, just still new to this.) But then why wouldn't a `git pull` or `git merge` be able to resolve this?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to work entirely, or maybe I'm missing something. After I did this, I ran `git branch -a`, which listed `test1`, `test2`, but also listed `/origin/test1` and `/origin/test2`. Basically, where I have three branches, `git branch -a` now lists six in total; three on my machine, three on origin. But this isn't the same behavior as you'd get from something like `git clone --mirror` or if I had set up the repo initially.

Comment: you have three _local_ branches and 3 remote branches... they don't necessarily go hand in hand... you might take your 3 local branches and move them all over the place.... other people might commit on the remote branches and you won't notice it until you fetch.... and then when you fetch you will see that the remote branches diverged from your local branches. Keep in mind that repos work separately.

Comment: Okay, but why is it that, in a repo I create on my machine (and similarly in the one that I `clone --mirror` (and set `bare = false`)), it doesn't show the 3 remote branches separately? As far as I can tell, it still is tracking the 3 remote branches, but it only shows the three local branches (without `origin/[branchname]`) even when `--all` is used. Is it the exact same but it just appears differently, or are there differences I'm unaware of?

Comment: what command exactly are you using to try to show the remote branches?

Comment: `git branch --all` or `git branch -a`. For example, on the repo I just cloned (not by `--mirror`, but normally), it outputs `master` and `origin/master`. On the other hand, I just made a new folder, ran `git clone --mirror repourl` on it, set it to not be `bare`, and then ran `git branch -a`. In this case, there is still an `origin` remote, so there is still a `master` and `origin/master`, but it doesn't show as two separate branches under `--all`. I can't figure why, unless there would be some difference in these methods that I'm unaware of.

Comment: `--mirror` option does have some spices there. Did you check `git help clone` to see what it does? Maybe that's the problem... I wouldn't know.

Comment: I'm marking this as solved. First, `--mirror` really isn't to be used in place of a regular `clone`, as you can't `fetch` from the repo afterward. There's definitely some stuff I don't understand, but it's clear enough that `clone --mirror` is doing something else. Second, @eftshift0, this page in particular in the Git Book was very illuminating. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches